# pandas how to groupby a period time and then get back a df after filtration inside the group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Basically, now I have a set of data from some routers(AP). The routers would probe user's devices every 3 seconds and give us user's MAC number(tag_mac).

In order to clean those data(since at a period of time, different APs would give us back same tag_macs if the user is near other aps ), I just need the APs with the strongest signal(indicated by rssi) within every 10 seconds(just take the average). This is a sample of my data.

```
         ap_mac  rssi       tag_mac                time
0  048b422149fa   -63  a40dbc018db7 2017-07-01 08:00:00
1  048b4223e63d   -72  a40dbc018db7 2017-07-01 08:00:00
2  048b4223e63d   -72  a40dbc018db7 2017-07-01 08:00:00
3  048b4223e63d   -72  a40dbc018db7 2017-07-01 08:00:00
4  048b4223e63d   -72  a40dbc018db7 2017-07-01 08:00:00
5  048b422149ff   -50  30b49e3715d0 2017-07-01 08:00:00
6  048b422149ff   -50  30b49e3715d0 2017-07-01 08:00:00
7  048b422149ff   -50  30b49e3715d0 2017-07-01 08:00:00
8  048b422149ff   -50  30b49e3715d0 2017-07-01 08:00:00
9  048b422149ff   -50  30b49e3715d0 2017-07-01 08:00:00
```

What I need is a filtered dataframe where I dropped all the rows has weaker rssi within every 10 seconds time period. So what I have left is a cleaned data where for each tag_mac I only have ap_macs with the strongest rssi.

Can anyone help me with it?
Thanks!

Comment: Your `time` column does not seem to vary at all, but you are claiming that the routers would probe user's devices ***every 3*** seconds. Shouldn't the time change for different rows for the same AP mac?

Comment: @Abdou hmmm...Right, I'll check my data, but that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: For instance the AP MAC `048b4223e63d` was probed four times, but all those probings happened at the same time: `2017-07-01 08:00:00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your problem right but you could use pandas Grouper such as :

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df = df.set_index('time')
result = df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10S'),'ap_mac','tag_mac']).mean().reset_index()
result.groupby(['time','tag_mac'])[['ap_mac','rssi']].max()
```

Edit :

I modified your table just to see how the code works such that :

```
         ap_mac  rssi       tag_mac                time
0  048b422149fa   -63  a40dbc018db7 2017-07-01 08:00:00
1  048b4223e63d   -72  a40dbc018db7 2017-07-01 08:00:10
2  048b4223e63d   -72  a40dbc018db7 2017-07-01 08:00:15
3  048b4223e63d   -72  a40dbc018db7 2017-07-01 08:00:00
4  048b4223e63d   -72  a40dbc018db7 2017-07-01 08:00:00
5  048b422149ff   -50  30b49e3715d0 2017-07-01 08:00:00
6  048b422149ff   -50  30b49e3715d0 2017-07-01 08:00:30
7  048b422149ff   -50  30b49e3715d0 2017-07-01 08:00:12
8  048b422149ff   -50  30b49e3715d0 2017-07-01 08:00:00
9  048b422149ff   -50  30b49e3715d0 2017-07-01 08:00:00
```

You want to group by **time** (every 10 seconds), **ap_mac** and **tag_mac** .

You first convert the time column to datetime using pd.to_datetime

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

In order to use TimeGrouper, you put the time as index (works only with DateTimeIndex)

```
df = df.set_index('time')
```

And you perform the groupby to get the mean of each tag_mac for each ap_mac every 10 seconds.

```
result = df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10S'),'ap_mac','tag_mac']).mean().reset_index()
```

And finally,

```
result.groupby(['time','tag_mac'])[['ap_mac', 'rssi']].max()
```

Output :

```
                                        ap_mac          rssi
time                    tag_mac         
2017-07-01 08:00:00     30b49e3715d0    048b422149ff    -50
                        a40dbc018db7    048b4223e63d    -63
2017-07-01 08:00:10     30b49e3715d0    048b422149ff    -50
                        a40dbc018db7    048b4223e63d    -72
2017-07-01 08:00:30     30b49e3715d0    048b422149ff    -50
```

Comment: I hope I am not being too unclear. What I want is: within every 10 secs, one tag-mac may accept signals from many ap-macs, but I only want rows containing the single ap-mac with the strongest average rssi in that 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks! It works almost as I desired. But it seems that you are returning max() of something, but you did not specify it is the max of rssi? And what I need is actually the max average over the same ap_mac in that 10s. So I can just claim that in that 10 seconds, the tag_mac was only detected by that ap_mac with the strongest average rssi.

Comment: thanks! It is very efficient! But since you grouped with tag and ap, so the shape of it is just a 1 columns data frame, with the group as index(correct me if am wrong), so how do we go from the result back to the original form with 4 columns?

Comment: also, is it a syntax error which should be <code>result = df.groupby(['ap_mac', 'tag_mac',pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10S')]).mean() </code>? why is there a "df." before the key?

Comment: you're right you can just do df.groupby(['ap_mac', 'tag_mac', pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10S']).mean().

Comment: you just have to do a reset_index() on your resulted dataframe  at the end to recover its original form with 4 columns ;)

Comment: oops. I just found it is not a right answer. When you do result = df.groupby(['ap_mac','tag_mac',pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10S')]).mean()
, you grouped both ap and tag, so when you take the mean you computed the mean of the same (ap,tag) tuple instead of taking the mean of rssi with respect to ap_mac within the tag_mac. For example, if we do it correctly, within every 10 seconds, for each tag_mac, we should only have one record. However, just as your output shows, we have two records for tag a40dbc018db7 in the first 10 seconds.

Comment: just change the order of groupby and it's okay, no? i edited the code & output take a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151584/discussion-between-jack-and-thomas-gerspacher).

Comment: Unfortunately, after reset_index(), the format is just as I expected, but the result is not correct(on my dataset). I manually checked for one specific tag_mac, and I found that in the first 10 seconds, the ap_mac you got is not the strongest, it does not have the max mean.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming  `df` as the DataFrame

```
#this makes sure that the 'date' column is in the required format
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'] , format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ap_mac','tag_mac','rssi','to','from'])

#start date - first date in the dataframe 'df'
start = pd.Timestamp(df.loc[0,'time'])

#end date is the last date in the dataframe 'df'
end = pd.Timestamp(df.loc[df.shape[0]-1,'time'])


upper = lower = start

indices_array =[]

while (end - upper >= pd.Timedelta(seconds=10)):

    upper = upper + pd.Timedelta(seconds=10)
    #data within a 10 second range is extracted into the variable data

    data = df[upper>df['time']][df['time']>=lower]

    for i in data['tag_mac'].unique():

        var = data.loc[data['tag_mac']==i].groupby('ap_mac').mean()
    #in the new_df rssi contains average values
        new_df = new_df.append({'rssi':var.max()[0],'ap_mac':var.idxmax()[0],'tag_mac':i,'to':upper,'from':lower},ignore_index=True)

    lower = upper
```

your huge dataset, as you mentioned, is condensed into the DataFrame `new_df` containing only the values you require

i've added to new columns `to` and `from` in the dataframe `new_df` showing the time range in which the reading is present

`new_df` contains all the `tag_mac`s and their corresponding `ap_mac`s that have max **Average** `rssi` values sampled every ten seconds.

if you face any difficulties feel free to leave a comment

Comment: Actually I have a fixed df with more than 5 million rows. The time is a given column, so I do not need to update the df as time grows. Is that what your code is doing?

Comment: Yes, within every 10sec, that's why I want to also groupby time period.

Comment: every AP only send data every 3seconds, but since I have a lot of aps, so yes, it is continuous.

Comment: Yes I do. I hope I am not being too unclear. What I want is: within every 10 secs, one tag-mac may accept signals from many ap-macs, but I only want rows containing the single ap-mac with strongest average rssi in that 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks! It is exactly what I needed! Just one more thing, in every 10 seconds, 1 ap may detect the same tag_mac 3 times, while for single one row, it may be the max, but on average it may be lower than another ap. Is there any way we could modify this?

Comment: updated the answer as per your request, see if it does what you need , if not just drop a comment ill look into it

Comment: it works, however the time complexity seems like a big issue....I used it on 59Mb sized data, and it took nearly 3 hours....maybe it is because you used append instead of taking index array? It seems that there is no neat way doing this request using pandas groupby method  since we would lose columns by grouping them together, and I don't know how to recover original data form from there.

Comment: i understand your problem. i'll see if i can make it faster